# Regex in Jsoup works in java project, not in Android project

Tags: java, android, regex, image, jsoup

I'm trying to get the thumbnails URL from a web-site using Jsoup HTML Parser
i need to extract all the URL's that ends with  60x60.jpg(or png)   (all thumbnails URL's ends with this URL)

The problem is that i get it to work in an ordinary Java Project,  but in Android it doesn't work. (regex problem)

This code works in Java Project:

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src~=(60x60).(png|jpg)]"); 
for (Element img : pngs) {
        String url = img.absUrl("src");
        {
            if (!urls.contains(url)) {
                urls.add(url);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then print the urls array..  it works in Java, not in Android project.

In Android the only regex that **works** is only this

```
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
```

it works ok on Android.. though i don't need all the links ending with .jpg

I tried using

```
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src~=(60x60)\\.(png|jpg)]");
```

still not good, even with one slash before .(png|jpg)

so is the problem in Regex? it works different in Android or what?  it can't be the parser problem since it works  on a normal Java Project..

Comment: If `img[src$=.jpg]` is supposed to be a regex, then it's definitely not doing what you're expecting it to do. It matches the string `img`, followed by exactly one character that can be `s`, `r`, `c`, `$`, `=`, `.`, `j`, `p` or `g`.

Comment: isn't a problem with '(' and ')' try to add escape char before em

Comment: @Tim it's a CSS selector, `~` dictates it's a regex selector

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker  ok tnx,  i used this "img[src$=60x60.jpg]"   but how can i add png also?  adding (jpg|png) doesn't work.  tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a difference between the Java regex engine and Android's Darvik engine.

I would simplify by using the `comma` [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), which applies an `or` to multiple selectors.

E.g.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<img src='foo-60x60.png'> <img src='bar-60x60.jpg'>");
Elements images = doc.select("img[src$=60x60.png], img[src$=60x60.jpg]");
System.out.println(images);
```

Gives:

```
<img src="foo-60x60.png" />
<img src="bar-60x60.jpg" />
```

Comment: hey good, it works, though i already tried the Jericho parser which is kinda 2 or 3 times faster o_O (from the URL)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JSoup or Android's regex implementation, but a regex that finds a string starting with `img=` and ending with `60x60.jpg` or `60x60.png` would be

```
\bimg=.*?60x60\.(jpg|png)\b
```

Perhaps you could post an excerpt of the text you're trying to parse. Possibly regex isn't the solution to your problem.

Comment: perhaps he is searching (60x60).png or (60x60).jpg and  '(' and ')' in "...(60x60)..." is a problem

Comment: @Selvin i saw this example on their site  [link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) -  img[src~=(?i)\.(png|jpe?g)]    so i replaced ?i with  60x60

Comment: "img[src~=(?i)60x60\\.(png|jpe?g)]" ... (?i) just means ignorecase